# Comparação de Strings em sqlServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia. 
Tenho duas strings definidas : '2.9.15' e '2.9.16';
Preciso de as comparar e dizer qual delas é a maior. 
Não sei como fazer.

Comment: Oque são estas strings? datas?

Comment: Maior no comprimento?

Comment: Não! São meras strings. São definidas como versões de uma determinada aplicação

Comment: Não. Dizer qual é a maior no numero. Neste caso tem que dizer que a 2.9.16 é a maior

Comment: @AnaCarvalho apenas com o exemplo acima fica dificil saber o que você define como maior, então gostara que você resolve-se as seguintes comparações: "`3.9.1` e `2.9.16`", "`2.15.1` e `2.9.16`", "`1.15.17` e `2.9.1`"

Comment: E por fim, as strings tem sempre a mesma quantidade de números?

Comment: @AnaCarvalho: atenção especial ao converter de string para número. Sugiro que teste as soluções propostas com valores como "2.1.9" e "2.1.20", por exemplo, e analise os resultados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei exatamente qual é a sua necessidade.

Assim seria uma opção para esse caso.

```
DECLARE @STR1 VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @STR2 VARCHAR(20)

SET @STR1 = '2.9.15'
SET @STR2 = '2.9.16'

IF CAST( REPLACE( @STR1,'.', '' ) AS NUMERIC) > CAST( REPLACE(@STR2,'.','' ) AS NUMERIC) 
   PRINT 'A PRIMEIRA' 
ELSE 
 IF CAST( REPLACE( @STR1,'.', '' ) AS NUMERIC) < CAST( REPLACE(@STR2,'.','' ) AS NUMERIC) 
      PRINT 'A SEGUNDA'
  ELSE 
      PRINT 'SAO IGUAIS'
```

Comment: Ajudou imenso. Era mesmo isso :) muito obrigada

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo: Olá Reginaldo. Quando possível avalie o código sugerido, utilizando os valores "2.1.30" e "2.12.0", por exemplo.

Comment: Comentei na resposta que não sabia exatamente qual era a real necessidade dela e disse que para aquele caso apresentado a resposta era positiva. Não discordo que em algumas condições a resposta é falha.

Answer (score 3):

Caso esta seja uma coluna de uma de suas tabelas, pode utilizar o *[Max()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187751.aspx)* dentro do seu *select* para pegar o maior valor, desta forma:

```
Select Max(sua_coluna) from sua_tabela
```

Se a comparação for ser feita entre duas *strings*, não existe uma 'função especifica' que faça isso, mas pode utilizar algo do tipo:

```
CASE
  WHEN String1 = String2 THEN 0 --Os valores são iguais
  WHEN String1 < String2 THEN String2
  WHEN String1 > String2 THEN String1
  ELSE NULL --Uma das strings tem o valor nulo
END
```

Comment: Também ajudou imenso :)

Comment: muito Obrigada :)

Comment: @LeoLonghi: Olá Leo. Quando possível avalie o código sugerido, utilizando os valores "2.1.30" e "2.12.0", por exemplo.

Comment: @JoséDiz se refere ao Max ou ao case?

Answer (score 0):

Comparações diretas de versão como string não são confiáveis. Por exemplo, "2.1.20" é mais atual do que "2.1.9" mas, ao comparar diretamente os dois valores, o valor retornado como mais atual é "2.1.9".

```
-- código #2
declare @V1 varchar(10), @V2 varchar(10);
set @V1= '2.1.9';
set @V2= '2.1.20'

IF @V1 > @V2
  SELECT @V1 + ' mais atual do que ' + @V2
else IF @V2 > @V1
       SELECT @V2 + ' mais atual do que ' + @V1
     else SELECT @V1 + ' é igual a ' + @V2;
```

Uma solução é converter o valor de string para numérico. Supondo que o número da versão seja composto por 3 partes e que cada parte possa variar de 0 a 999, segue solução em que o string de versão é convertido em valor numérico utilizando a fórmula: a primeira parte é multiplicada por 10^6, a segunda por 10^3 e a terceira por 10^0. Por exemplo:

```
"2.1.30" = 2 * 10^6 + 1 * 10^3 + 30 = 2.000.000 + 1.000 + 30 = 2.001.030
"2.12.0" = 2 * 10^6 + 12 * 10^3 + 0 = 2.000.000 + 12.000 + 0 = 2.012.000
```

O código fica então assim:

```
-- código #1 v3
declare @versãoA varchar(10), @versãoB varchar(10);
set @versãoA= '2.1.9';
set @versãoB= '2.1.20';

-- converte valor string em numérico
declare @versãoA_n int, @versãoB_n int;
set @versãoA_n= cast(parsename(@versãoA, 3) as int) * power(10, 6) + 
                cast(parsename(@versãoA, 2) as int) * power(10, 3) + 
                cast(parsename(@versãoA, 1) as int);
set @versãoB_n= cast(parsename(@versãoB, 3) as int) * power(10, 6) + 
                cast(parsename(@versãoB, 2) as int) * power(10, 3) + 
                cast(parsename(@versãoB, 1) as int);

-- retorna o mais recente. Se forem iguais, retorna NULL
SELECT Recente= case when @versãoA_n > @versãoB_n 
                     then @versãoA
                     else case when @versãoA_n < @versãoB_n 
                               then @versãoB
                               else NULL
                          end
                end;
```

A solução acima utiliza a função [PARSENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188006.aspx) para obter as partes da numeração de versão. Outra forma (mais trabalhosa) de obter as partes é através da utilização das funções SUBSTRING e CHARINDEX.

O código #1 assume que as versões terão sempre 3 partes. Entretanto, se o número de partes for variável, outra abordagem é necessária.